# geometry nodes increase diameter per instance

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'd like to generate a 3d printer tests
To have a seperates series of cylinders and with 1 cm towards 1.1 cm
And do a 10 steps increment of width 1.00 1.01 1.02 etc

The same for a hole and cubes.

Essentially i'm trying to find the ideal widths for a lock and fit and a fit that still allows for rotation.
To find the margins for future 3d printed technical designs with blender, and my printer.
I tried starting with a nurbs line but i dont understand the system well enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve it like this:

Create a line with the node `Mesh Line`.

Then instantiate a cube with the dimensions *1x1*.

Multiply the index of each point by $0.01$ and add $1$. This gives you incremental values from $1.0$ to $1.1$ for a number of *11* points.

Finally use these values as scaling in the node `Instance on Points`.

[image]